# Showing $\rho_{Hom}\cdot \phi(v)=\rho_W\cdot \phi\cdot \rho_V^{-1} v$.

Tags: representation-theory

I am wanting to show using the isomorphism $Hom(V,W) \cong W \otimes V^*$ that:
$$\rho_{Hom}\cdot \phi(v)=\rho_W\cdot \phi\cdot \rho_V^{-1} v$$
I know that we need to use the relation:
$$\rho_{W\otimes V^*}(w\otimes \lambda)=\rho_W w\otimes \rho_{V^*}\lambda$$
but am not sure how to correctly write $\rho_{Hom}\cdot \phi(v)$ in terms of $\rho_{W\otimes V^*}$ etc. Please can someone explain.

(Notation used: $\rho_V$ is the representation $\rho_V: G\rightarrow GL(V)$ for convenience $\rho_V\equiv \rho_V(g)$. $\phi \in Hom(V,W)$, $v \in V$, $w \in W$ and $\lambda \in V^*$.)

Comment: Can you explain all your notation?  What is $\phi$ and what are all the $\rho$s?

Comment: @EricWofsey see edit

Answer (score 1):

The key point here is unraveling how the isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)\cong W\otimes V^*$ is defined.  Specifically, this isomorphism is the unique linear map that sends $w\otimes\lambda\in W\otimes V^*$ to the map $v\mapsto \lambda(v)w$ in $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$.  Morever, maps of the form $v\mapsto \lambda(v)w$ span $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$, and the equation you wish to prove is linear in $\phi$.  Thus in order to prove it, we may assume that $\phi$ has this form and corresponds to an element of the form $w\otimes \lambda\in W\otimes V^*$.

Now it's just a matter of computation.  Since $\rho_{W\otimes V^*}(w\otimes \lambda)=\rho_W w\otimes \rho_{V^*}\lambda$, this means that $\rho_{Hom}(\phi)$ is the map $V\to W$ which sends $v$ to $(\rho_{V^*}\lambda)(v)\rho_W w$.  We now have 
\begin{align*}
(\rho_{Hom}\phi)(v)&=(\rho_{V^*}\lambda)(v)\rho_W w \\
&=\lambda(\rho_V^{-1}(v))\rho_W w \\
&=\rho_W(\lambda(\rho_V^{-1}(v))w) \\
&= \rho_W(\phi(\rho_V^{-1}(v)))
\end{align*}
just as you want. (The second equality is the definition of $\rho_{V^*}$, the third equality is linearity of $\rho_W$, and the last equality is just the fact that $\phi(x)=\lambda(x)w$ for any $x$.)

Comment: please could you expand on why $\rho_{W\otimes V^*}(w\otimes \lambda)=\rho_W w\otimes \rho_{V^*}\lambda$ means that $\rho_{Hom}(\phi)$ is the map $V\to W$ which sends $v$ to $(\rho_{V^*}\lambda)(v)\rho_W w$?

Comment: By definition of the isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)\cong W\otimes V^*$, the element $\rho_W w\otimes \rho_{V^*}\lambda\in W\otimes V^*$ corresponds to the map $v\mapsto (\rho_{V^*}\lambda)(v)\rho_W w$ in $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$.